# How to reference `bundle.js` from html after `cachebust.resources()` has created `bundle.a3503174.js`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, browser-cache

The link at https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js seems to generate a bundle file with the name `bundle.a3503174.js`, however, it is referenced in the html as `bundle.js`. How does that work? How does the system know where to look at the correct bundle file although the name has been extended with an md5 checksum number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the question actually uses `gulp-cachebust` to both create the bundle and then rewrite the reference to that bundle within index.html to the appropriate filename. The key lies in the statement `cachebust.references()` within the following lines of code.

```
gulp.task('build', [ 'clean', 'bower','build-css','build-template-cache', 'jshint', 'build-js'], function() {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(cachebust.references())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); });
```

So although the reference link within the non-gulp version of index.html is `/dist/js/bundle.js`. That reference is rewritten as `js/bundle.a3503174.js` within the gulp version of index.html.